# Firebase not getting new Data, after Android app was idle

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

***Info:***

I am doing an application where multiple Users need to work on one project. There are a few tasks that need to be completed.

***Problem:***

When a user turns off his screen, and turns it on around 5 minutes later (Or he went to the Homescreen or any other app for around 5 min ), firebase takes up to a Minute to get the new Data into the App (I have offline storing off btw). It frustrates the Users, because the Data needs to be up to date all the time so they can work with updated Tasks.

*EDIT*: **THIS IS HAPPENING EVERYWHERE IN ALL IMPLEMENTATIONS LIKE THE EXAMPLE BELOW**

***Question:***

Why is it like this?
How can I solve it???

*EDIT*: ***Example:***

```
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference doc = db.collection("user").document(email).collection("dates").document(date);
doc.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {

                    HashMap CodeMap = (HashMap) document.getData();
                    Set keySet = CodeMap.keySet();
                    Object[] key = keySet.toArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < keySet.size(); i++) {

                        if (!key[i].equals("clockIn") && !key[i].equals("clockOut") && !key[i].equals("completeTime") && !key[i].equals("clockPauseFrom") && !key[i].equals("clockPauseTo")) {

                            userWorkList.add(new User_Work_View_Row(key[i].toString(), email, date, i));
                            System.out.println(key[i] + " FOUND");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }
        }

                });
```

***SOLUTION:**** (Kind of)

I have Implemented the solution of the answer below and did some Testing with the Battery options.

I found out that disabling Battery Optimizations and Background restrictions(if its even there) works! The Data is coming right away. I don't think its a good solution but it works for my App.

Comment: if data is updating then there might be internet issues.

Comment: @Harkal The Internet on ALL the phones stays connected. The same Issue persists on the Emulator too.

Comment: so what you come back to the app it takes a minute to update the data ? it think there might be something wrong in the implementaion. will you post the implementaion ?

Comment: @Harkal I have edited the question with an example tell me if you need more info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're observing is likely a result of an [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) in the frequency of connection retries performed by the Firestore SDK.  This backoff saves much battery compared to always retrying immediately in a tight loop.

If you want to force a retry, then you could try manually calling [disableNetwork()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#disableNetwork()) followed by [enableNetwork()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#enableNetwork()) to get it to retry immediately.

Comment: Thanks I will test it right now and see if it works!

Comment: I have implemented it into my app, and I must say it works better, but on some phones (like my Samsung S 10 lite ) it still hangs a bit not one Minute but like 10-20 seconds